# How to change ELABEL on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to change elabel of edge.

```
agens=# create (:v1{id:1})-[:e1{id:3}]->(:v1{id:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 1)
agens=# match ()-[r1:e1{id:3}]->() set r1:v2 remove r1:v1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: match ()-[r1:e1{id:3}]->() set r1:v2 remove r1:v1;
                                         ^
```

But, there is an error on it.

How to change ELABEL on AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change label on edge on AgensGraph.

But, You can try add new edge with same properties and remove old edge.

```
agens=# create (:v1{id:1})-[:e1{id:3}]->(:v1{id:2});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 1)
agens=# match p = ( (n1)-[r1]->(n2) ) return p;
                               p                               
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [v1[3.1]{"id": 1},e1[4.1][3.1,3.2]{"id": 3},v1[3.2]{"id": 2}]
(1 row)

agens=# match  (n1)-[r1:e1{id:3}]->(n2)
        create (n1)-[r2:e2]->(n2)
        set    r2 = properties(r1)
        delete r1;
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 0, INSERT EDGE 1, DELETE VERTEX 0, DELETE EDGE 1, UPDATE PROPERTY 1)
agens=# match p = ( (n1)-[r1]->(n2) ) return p;
                               p                               
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [v1[3.1]{"id": 1},e2[5.1][3.1,3.2]{"id": 3},v1[3.2]{"id": 2}]
(1 row)
```